Modify byval target as range to copy values and formatting only
I have the following Macro which works.
However I would like to modify it so that it only copies values formatting.  Not formulas.
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Modified 2/22/2020 11:42:10 AM EST
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 31 Then
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("Open").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim ans As Long
    ans = Target.Row
    If Target.Value = "Y" Then
    Rows(ans).Copy Sheets("open").Rows(Lastrow)
    
    End If
    End If
    End Sub

I tried modifying various things I read non of which I could compile.

PasteSpecial?  Try recording a macro if you're unsure about the syntax.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial


Try Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Microsoft documentation:

Range.PasteSpecial method (Excel)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Modified 2/22/2020 11:42:10 AM EST
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 31 Then
        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Lastrow = Sheets("Open").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Dim ans As Long
        ans = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "Y" Then
            Rows(ans).Copy
            Sheets("open").Rows(Lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Update:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Modified 2/22/2020 11:42:10 AM EST
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 31 Then
        If Target.Value = "Y" Then
            Dim dRng As Range
            Set dRng = Sheets("Open").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
            Target.EntireRow.Copy dRng
            dRng.Value = dRng.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Thanks that works.  Is it possible to include the conditional formatting as well?

Hmmm now I realise I should have done a previous step.  Is it possible when I change the cell to "Y" to copy and paste the values and formating of a three seperate cells in the same worksheet and row without changing the rest?  Sorry to be a pain
